# Which is correct upfront or upfrontly

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction

I want to express to another person how much he is willing to pay for a task and he can openly tell me. Upfront seems a good word for this.
Which of the two sentences is correct:

1. You can let me know the price upfront
2. you can let me know the price upfrontly

Answer (score 2):

"Upfront" (or "Up front") is correct, as you're asking him to tell you at the start (which is what "up front" means).

Because "upfront" is a preposition you can't do something "upfrontly" any more than you can do something "fromly".

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that "upfrontly" is not a word and is therefore never correct.

Comment: Why is upfront a preposition? Dictionary says it's an adjective/adverb? Thanks

Comment: So, you can be "upfront" with someone which means honest/transparent, but in the context of your usage you're saying *when* you want to know the price, i.e. at the start.